# The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream. (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gzip

All of a sudden I've encountered an issue with the error 'The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.' I have looked at similar posts, but can't find a solution for me.

I suspect this is due to an issue with DB changes made using Entity Framework. Locally I made the changes using Code-First which worked fine. However, when posting to production I need to manually run the scripts for any required changes and that's worked many times before. I have managed to replicate the issue locally. I have shown below where the error is coming from and the relevant stack trace. Any suggestions?

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

[InvalidDataException: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.]
   System.IO.Compression.GZipDecoder.ReadHeader(InputBuffer input) +782
   System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode() +158
   System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length) +140
   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +89
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreamInput(Uri baseUri, String baseUriStr, Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, Encoding encoding) +295
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitStream() +65
   System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(Stream input, Uri baseUri, String baseUriString, XmlParserContext inputContext) +118
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor.Decompress(Byte[] bytes) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel(String& migrationId, String& productVersion, String contextKey) +1207
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +50
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +74
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +71
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +155
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +482
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +177
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +272
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +69
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +66
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +209
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +172
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +498
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +43
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +372
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +31
   AngliaWeb.Controllers.<Login>d__11.MoveNext() in D:\Code\Anglia\AngliaWeb\AngliaWeb\Controllers\AccountController.cs:79
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +396
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +46
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +651
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by deleting every record from the MigrationHistory table.